# Merging files in hdfs using java program

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I am new to big data and was working on a small task where i need to merge multiple files into a single file in hdfs. I was using Java program to accomplish this(merging all files similar to prod* into a single prod.txt file). I had searched for help and the code i have written so far is:

public class MergeFiles {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String srcPath = "/user/demouser/first/prod*"; 
    String dstPath = "/user/demouser/second/prod.txt"; 
    Configuration conf = new Configuration(); 
    conf.set("fs.default.name","http://hostname:portnumber/");
    try 
    { 
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf); 
        FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), false, conf, null); 
        } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    { }

    }
```

}

It is not working and i am not able to figure out how to resolve this. I also did not understand the working of "fs.default.name". Please help.

Comment: what about change your srcPath  to your  folder name  . I also use this api  well   please show your logs

Comment: That property is deprecated. It should be `fs.defaultFS`, and it needs to point at the namenode

Comment: Besides that, you're reinventing the wheel. Search a thing called filecrush. Or at the very least, Pig could do this in about 3 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a real hostname and portnumber there to replace 'http://hostname:portnumber/', your hostname and portnumber must be accessible from your computer.  It should be the location of your filesystem.

Comment: i have those already.. i have just replaced it with dummy names here. The files are also present at the location.

Comment: You need to see the IOException that you are catching, here you catch it and then do nothing - have a look at the javadoc for Exception to find out more, and also google for 'java exception handling'.

Comment: HDFS isn't a HTTP protocol. It's RPC